# Is the powerset question really an (indefinitely expansive) series of questions?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, set-theory

At the "end of the day," it has turned out that:

1. If we deny the powerset axiom, then the expression "the powerset of the zeroth aleph" refers to nothing, in which case there is an "empty forcing" of the natural powerset (it is forced to equal nothing, not even a dialethic version of the zeroth aleph and its powerset).
2. But if we do switch to dialethism, we could force the natural powerset to be both equal to the zeroth aleph (per whatever intuitions about infinity) as well as larger than the same.
3. Alternatively, if we hold fast the powerset axiom but not the well-ordering lemma (or any principle from which the WOL is typically derived, e.g. choice), we can force the natural powerset to stand outside the whole aleph series whatsoever, as an unorderly cardinal in some paraverse of its own.
4. If we hold fast the powerset axiom and the WOL,  we can force the natural powerset to be anything not cofinal with the zeroth aleph. In a sense, we can also force the powersets of all the ℵ<sub>*n*</sub> to equal the same much higher aleph, ℵ<sub>ω+1</sub> say (or ℵ<sub>ω<sup>447</sup>+231</sub>, or whatever). Now if we do this, though, we have also technically suppressed the possibility of the natural powerset being cofinal with any cardinal prior to the one selected. So there is a sense in which, "The natural powerset can be cofinal with the first aleph," is at least once-removed from the sphere of immediate possibility as such (ditto for, "It can be cofinal with the second aleph," &c.). In fact, we can force the powersets of whichever alephs to similarly line up, depending as we please on which universe in the unrestricted multiverse we see fit to venture in (so, for example, the powersets of all alephs in the interval [ℵ<sub>0</sub>, ℵ<sub>ω<sub>1</sub></sub>] could be forced to equal ℵ<sub>ω<sub>1</sub>+1</sub>, then for the interval [ℵ<sub>ω<sub>1</sub>+1</sub>, ℵ<sub>ω<sub>447</sub></sub>] we could make all the powersets equal ℵ<sub>ω<sub>ω<sub>ω</sub></sub>+117,532</sub>, and so on and on).
5. In fact, if we warp our axioms some more, in another direction, [we can even force the zeroth aleph's powerset (and by extension *every* infinite powerset) to equal the entire universe of sets (or at least ORD,](https://etheses.whiterose.ac.uk/29589/1/Thesis.pdf) though I imagine |ORD| = |CARD| is true, and in fact it is possible to have |ORD| not equal to |CARD|, somehow).
6. Also, Victoria Gitman, et. al. go over a way to make comprehensive sets of reals have countable cofinality, although this is done in a theory where the powerset axiom is suppressed ("What is the theory ZFC minus powerset?").
7. Finally, by fiddling with the Benacerraf problem some, modulo the suppression of the foundation axiom, I was able to contrive a way to force the powersets of even finite sets to be almost anything, so that the equivalence of ℘(*n*) and 2<sup>*n*</sup> comes apart. I'm not very confident in the reasoning I used to reach that conclusion, but by now, I wouldn't be surprised if it turned out that my reasoning is correct (I got an intuition about the Continuum being the size of the entire universe of sets when I reflected on the ability of the surreal numbers to map over 1/ω<sub>*a*</sub>, for any ordinal *a*; so the same kind of intuition is backing me up on this other count).

However, in the SEP article on [the philosophy of mathematics in general](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philosophy-mathematics/#SetThe) it is made note of that:

> Gödel’s hope that large cardinal axioms could solve the continuum problem turned out to be unfounded. The continuum hypothesis is independent of ZFC even in the context of large cardinal axioms. Nevertheless, large cardinal principles have manage to settle restricted versions of the continuum hypothesis (in the affirmative). The existence of so-called Woodin cardinals ensures that sets definable in analysis are either countable or the size of the continuum. Thus the ***definable** continuum problem* is settled. [emphasis added]

The definable powerset operation is the one that minimally satisfies Cantor's theorem (which merely tells us that there are elements in powersets that are not relevant counterparts of elements in base sets). If it is possible for the so-called "full" powerset of the zeroth aleph (and any other set) to be forced to equal anything larger whatsoever otherwise, is it possible that the powerset question, i.e., "What is the powerset of such-and-such set?" is really a constellation of questions? In this sense, ℘(*X*) and 2<sup>*X*</sup> might come apart again, in that the exponential would be meant to cover only a certain range of the powerset function/question. Accordingly, transfinite arithmetic could be constrained regardless of what the "full" powerset of anything is supposed to be; and moreover, options like universe-sized powersets can be reinterpreted in terms of being able to take any infinity of terms and represent the absolutely infinite thereby (c.f. Skolem's paradox, then).

**If the question of the powerset function is not reimagined as a plurality of questions (with a corollary hierarchy of some answers, perhaps), do (1) through (7) indicate that the question is not actually meaningful at all? Or rather, do (1) through (7) represent a near-equivalent of a logical explosion over the singular, instead of plural, powerset axiom (scheme)?** What I mean is something like: not to ask just, "What is *the* natural powerset?" but to ask a series of questions with no "full" (final) representation (except modulo (5)), starting from, "What is the definable natural powerset?" and then proceeding to, say, "What is the hyperdefinable natural powerset?" all the way up to (for the sake of (5)), "What is the ultradefinable natural powerset?"

**Addendum.** To distinguish this idea from Hamkins' "nightmare" solution to CH, I would offer that whereas Hamkins' account of the powerset problem is more like, "One problem, with different solutions in different universes," mine is, "Multiple problems, but each problem has only one (legitimate) solution." Now I don't need to maintain such a strong claim, perhaps, but for example, I would say, "The definable powerset question has the same answer in any legitimate universe," but on the other hand, I could also say, "There are different metadefinable powerset questions in different universes." So for example, a universe with unorderly cardinals allows for, "What is the unorderly powerset of the zeroth aleph?" whereas in the standard ascent, this question is not admissible.

Comment: Oh man, I must be losing my soul or something because this is like the second time in a row that a post of mine here has brought up the, "Are you a robot?" test :(